# How to pass remove functionality to modal component?

Tags: reactjs

Goal: Take removeStory function and place in a modal component. So user sees a story and wants to delete it. When user presses remove button a modal pops up to confirm decision. I managed the last few hours to create the modal state and component but have a problem. I don't understand how to get the removeStory function to work in my modal component. I got it working to delete a post in the Stories.js, but can't get it working in the modal component to delete the corresponding post. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoUZg.jpg)

What I tried: I passed the function via a custom global hook to my Modal component. Some how I need to have an id passed as an argument for the removeStory function parameter when invoked. I just need some guidance on what to do as I am close.

For your convenience I stripped down the components and left out the reducer.js.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Stories from './Stories';
import Modal from './Modal';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context';
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <SearchForm />
            <Stories />
            <Buttons />
            <Modal />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**context.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

import {
    SET_LOADING,
    SET_STORIES,
    REMOVE_STORY,
    HANDLE_PAGE,
    HANDLE_SEARCH,
} from './actions';
import reducer from './reducer';

const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?';

const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    hits: [],
    query: '',
    page: 0,
    nbPages: 0,
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const fetchStories = async (url) => {
        dispatch({ type: SET_LOADING });
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            dispatch({
                type: SET_STORIES,
                payload: { hits: data.hits, nbPages: data.nbPages },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const removeStory = (id) => {
        dispatch({ type: REMOVE_STORY, payload: id });
    };

    const handleSearch = (query) => {
        dispatch({ type: HANDLE_SEARCH, payload: query });
    };

    const handlePage = (value) => {
        dispatch({ type: HANDLE_PAGE, payload: value });
    };

    const openModal = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchStories(`${API_ENDPOINT}query=${state.query}&page=${state.page}`);
    }, [state.query, state.page]);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                ...state,
                removeStory,
                handleSearch,
                handlePage,
                isModalOpen,
                openModal,
                closeModal,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
    return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

**Stories.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context';

const Stories = () => {
    const { isLoading, hits, removeStory } = useGlobalContext();
    const { openModal } = useGlobalContext();

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div className='loading'></div>;
    }
    return (
        <section className='stories'>
            {hits.map((story) => {
                const { objectID, title, num_comments, url, points, author } = story;
                console.log(story);
                return story && url ? (
                    <article key={objectID} className='story'>
                        <h4 className='title'>{title}</h4>
                        <p className='info'>
                            {points} points by <span>{author} | </span>
                            {num_comments} comments
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <a
                                href={url}
                                className='read-link'
                                target='_blank'
                                rel='noopener noreferrer'
                            >
                                <span class='links'>read more</span>
                            </a>
                            <a className='remove-btn' onClick={() => removeStory(objectID)}>
                                <span class='links'>remove</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button className='btn' onClick={openModal}>
                                show modal
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                ) : null;
            })}
        </section>
    );
};

export default Stories;
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context';

const Modal = () => {
    const { isModalOpen, closeModal, hits, removeStory } = useGlobalContext();

    return (
        <div
            className={`${
                isModalOpen ? 'modal-overlay show-modal' : 'modal-overlay'
            }`}
        >
            <div className='modal-container'>
                <h3>Are you sure you want to remove this post?</h3>
                <div>
                    <a className='remove-btn' onClick={() => removeStory(hits.objectID)}>
                        <span class='links'>remove</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <button className='close-modal-btn' onClick={closeModal}>
                    <FaTimes />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

**Updated code:**

In context.js add state (placeholder to hold id).

```
const [activeStoryId, setActiveStory] = useState();
```

In context.js pass the id (same id param as removeStory function) into openModal function.

```
const openModal = (id) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setActiveStory(id);
};
```

In context.js update removeStory function to set modal state to false so it closes when user deletes or removes post.

```
const removeStory = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: REMOVE_STORY, payload: id });
    setIsModalOpen(false);
};
```

In context.js pass down activeStoryId to Provider.

```
 return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                ...state,
                removeStory,
                handleSearch,
                handlePage,
                isModalOpen,
                openModal,
                closeModal,
                activeStoryId,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
 };
```

In Modal.js pass activeStoryId to component via global context hook.

```
const { isModalOpen, closeModal, removeStory, activeStoryId } =
    useGlobalContext();
```

In Modal.js pass the activeStoryId to removeStory function in onClick event.

```
<a className='remove-btn' onClick={() => removeStory(activeStoryId)}>
    <span class='links'>remove</span>
</a>
```

In Stories.js, when you open modal you are going to grab the id (objectID) and pass as the argument in the openModal function. Remember the objectID comes from the API which is essentially the id of the story.

```
<button className='btn' onClick={() => openModal(objectID)}>
```

Now everything works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, in your `context.js` add one more state

```
const [activeStoryId, setActiveStory] = useState();
```

Then change he `openModel` to

```
const openModal = (storyId) => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setActiveStory(storyId);
};
```

In `Stories.js` pass the id in `openModel`

```
<button className='btn' onClick={() => openModal(objectId)}>
      show modal
</button>
```

Now you can access the `activeStoryId` in your Modal and pass it to the remove function

For optimisation you can discard `setIsModalOpen(true);` and use only
`setActiveStory(storyId);`, in the model instead of checking for the boolean value check if `activeId` exist. You can reset the `activeId` when you close the modal or remove the storie

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now and I will update my answer to confirm. Basically I am grabbing the id of each story from the API and passing it to the openModal function so the right id is grabbed when the open modal is clicked vs clicking the link in the modal.

Comment: Just updated my code to reflect your answer. Please let me know if I understood correctly. thanks

Comment: You did right, one optimization you can do is that, you can remove the setIsModalOpen(true) and use activeStoryId to open the model itself. That is of activeStoryId is not undefined open the model, and for closing it set it to undefined. By doning that you can ditch isModalOpen and reduce one state update

Comment: Perfect, I will look into doing that. Thanks again my friend :)

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding :)